# Symfony access control forbids user with correct role

Tags: security, symfony, access-control

security.yml:

```
role_hierarchy:
    admin: [test, simple]

providers:
    database:
        entity: { class: UserBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    prod:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: database
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            login_path: public_login
            check_path: public_login_check
            default_target_path: dashboard
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: public_login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/(.+), roles: admin }
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

When i login, I get 403 forbidden exception. Then i check profiler/security, and roles looks like that:

```
Roles   [ROLE_USER, admin]
```

When i switch access control to:

```
- { path: ^/(.+), roles: ROLE_USER }
```

It works fine.

Why the hell my access control doesn't allow me to access pages with "admin" role, but does with "ROLE_USER" ?

My goal is to drop built-in roles (like ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN etc), because I'm writing application for existing database, which contains already defined roles for users, so i want to use them.

Comment: I believe that the Symfony security component expects role names to follow the `ROLE_*` format. I don't know of any exposed way to change this, you'll probably need to dig into the source and see if it's something that you could extend / override in your own class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have confirmed that 'ROLE_' prefix is required - its because symfony by default use its own [RoleVoter implementation](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/RoleVoter.html).

To get rid of this prefix, custom RoleVoter is needed. To do that you need to create custom class implementing [RoleVoterInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/VoterInterface.html), make it service and tag it with 'security.voter', to enforce security layer to use it instead of default one.

[Read more about implementing own RoleVoters on this example.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html)

Comment: That was in my answer approx 9 days before.. you should consider accepting it instead :)

Comment: Nope, you only said that in symfony i have to use ROLE_ADMIN, which is not true and helpful at all, because i could even use ROLE_admin, and it would work out of box, and would be better then ROLE_ADMIN, because my roles are stored in database in lower case, so I could just add ROLE_ prefix in getRoles() method. You didnt even suggested that way. However I found best solution, so even "admin" role would work - you didnt even said Its possible and very easy to do. You just sait that i have to use ROLE_ADMIN - i knew it already.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the right syntax for roles in the Security configuration
you should change

```
- { path: ^/(.+), roles: admin }
```

To:

```
 - { path: ^/(.+), roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```